# Pre-formatted UITextView content from file

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have a file with text that should be displayed in a UITextView. I would like to add support of formatting of this text like bold.

Is it possible to define these formatting options in the file and load it into a NSAttributedString? All examples I have found so far, sets a specific range of the string to e.g. bold, but I would like to preserve this formatting options in the file on disk.

**On other words**
Is it possible to write some mark down kind of text in the file and load it directly into a UITextView while preserving text formatting.

Comment: Question not clear to us. Please edit and restructure it more properly..

Comment: @dahiya_boy I tried to make it more clear.

Comment: @7heViking - are you familiar with HTML formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose all text in file content in HTML `<b></b>` tag and load it in `NSAttributedString` using some `initWithHTML:` initializer, like

> ```
> - (nullable instancetype)initWithHTML:(NSData *)data 
>      documentAttributes:(NSDictionary<NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributeKey,
> id> * _Nullable * _Nullable)dict;
> ```

Comment: It lead me to this solution: `[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                     options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                             NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                          documentAttributes:nil error:nil];`